# Java issue - Java is causing Internet Explorer 9 to crash when clicking a javascript link that opens a java applet

Tags: windows-7, java, internet-explorer, crash

I have multiple users that have this problem come up at what seems random. Customers computers are Windows 7 64 bit. Using Internet Explorer 9 and Java 8 update 65.

What occurs is we have a home grown Java application that is accessed by users via a link in Internet Explorer. Normally, when the customers click the link it starts the Java applet. The issue occurs when the customer clicks the link, Internet Explorer crashes and reloads and shows the yellow bar at the bottom that states that an add-on has caused Internet Explorer to crash.

Now the workaround to get it working on the customers computer is to recreate the users account on that computer. Typically if another user logs into the same computer they do not have this issue. So I have narrowed it down to being profile specific. Now usually this isn't to big of a deal, but we have a lot of people that have software that is profile specific and this require me having to reinstall that program which can take some time. I have gone about deleting the users "virtualstore" Sun folder and any other sun or java folders in the users profile that I can find. Those don't have any effect on the users computer.

If anyone knows of any possible ways of fixing this without recreating the users computer account I would be very appreciative.